# How to call standardGeneric with a variable function name

Tags: r, r-s4

The following code throws a warning:

```
test_slot = "testslot"

setGeneric(name = test_slot, 
           def = function(object){
               standardGeneric(test_slot)
           },
           where = globalenv()
)



[1] "testslot"
Warning message:
In .recursiveCallTest(body, fname) :
  the body of the generic function for ‘testslot’ calls 'standardGeneric' to dispatch on a different name ("test_slot")!
```

I would have expected that it would have been equivalent to:

```
setGeneric(name = "testslot", 
           def = function(object){
               standardGeneric("testslot")
           },
           where = globalenv()
)
```

**What happened?**

Answer (score 1):

This does not answer why the original block of code failed, but a workaround would be to do:

```
test_slot = "testslot"

setGeneric(name = test_slot, 
           def = eval(parse(text = paste0("function(object){",

           "standardGeneric('", test_slot, "')",
       "}")))
           },
           where = globalenv()
)
```

that is, construct the entire `def` argument to be an evaluated function.